# Как нажимать на клавиатуру в java как в pyautogui в python

Tags: java

И так, я знаю что в python есть библиотека pyautogui и она может сделать эмитацию нажатий на клавиатуру

```
pyautogui.press('f11') # нажмёт на F11 
pyautogui.click() # Клиенет
pyautogui.hotkey('win', 'r') # нажмёт на горячую клавишу Win + r
pyautogui.typewrite('Hello world!!') # напишет текст Hello world!
```

но как всё то сделать в java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

java.awt.Robot

```
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_1);
```